# how to get json datetime with UTC string instead of GMT from postgresql using python

Tags: python, json, postgresql, datetime

I use sqlalchemy core for defining the table as:

```
tasks = Table("tasks", metadata,
              Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
              Column("description", String, nullable=False),
              Column("created_on",DateTime(timezone=True)),
              # assigned_date is start_date
              Column("assigned_date", DateTime(timezone=True)),
              Column("due_date", DateTime(timezone=True)))
```

When I list the tasks using json o/p, I get the date string as:

```
{
  "task_list": [
    {
      "created_on": "Tue, 12 Dec 2016 00:00:00 GMT", 
      "description": null, 
      "id": 5, 
      "assigned_date": "Tue, 28 Jan 2017 07:14:34 GMT", 
      "due_date": "Tue, 12 Feb 2017 07:14:34 GMT", 
    }
  ]
}
```

In json o/p, I wish to display the UTC string. How do I do it? Using postgresql 9.4, sqlalchemy core 1.0, python 2.7 and flask for API calls
Though I have read in several posts both GMT and UTC are the same

Answer (score 0):

UTC is a system of timekeeping, while GMT is a timezone.
GMT is the timezone at 0:00 offset from UTC; there is no difference between GMT and timezone +0:00

Comment: I am totally aware that they are the same, but if I get the value showing 'UTC' string instead of 'GMT', the browser will automatically convert the time to the local timezone and display to the client, and will avoid all the conversion algorithm